# Python error: unbound method distance() must be called with Point instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

On executing the below code

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distance(self,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        d = math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ** 2) + ((y2 - y1) ** 2))
        print ("Distance between the points is " + "%0.6f" % d)
        return d

def main():
    x = float(input("Enter x coordinate of first circle's centre: "))
    y = float(input("Enter y coordinate of the first circle's centre: "))
    r = float(input("Enter first circle's radius: "))
    pointx1 = x
    pointy1 = y
    first_circle = circle(x, y, r)
    print(first_circle)
    x = float(input("\nEnter x coordinate of second circle's centre: "))
    y = float(input("Enter y coordinate of the second circle's centre: "))
    r = float(input("Enter second circle's radius: "))
    pointx2 = x
    pointy2 = y
    second_circle = circle(x, y, r)
    Point.distance(Point,pointx1, pointy1, pointx2, pointy2)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/Deepak/PycharmProjects/Submission/Shapes.py",line 102,in main 
Point.distance(Point,pointx1, pointy1, pointx2, pointy2)
TypeError: unbound method distance() must be called with Point instance as 
first argument (got classobj instance instead)
```

I am trying to read the center coordinates and radius of two circles from the user and then I am trying to determine the distance between their centers.I tried sending only four parameters to Point.distance() but that also returned an error. Please help.What should I do to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you got wrong what I think you might got wrong, but you do not pass an argument for `self`, you only pass `pointx1, pointy1, pointx2, pointy2`, the `self` is handled *internally*. Actually your distance function is not really taking advantage of the class structure. You might think of, e.g.:

```
from math import sqrt

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y


    @classmethod
    def two_point_distance(cls, pnt1, pnt2):
        return sqrt( ( pnt1.x - pnt2.x )**2 + ( pnt1.y - pnt2.y )**2 )


    def distance_to(self, pnt2):
        return sqrt( ( self.x - pnt2.x )**2 + ( self.y - pnt2.y )**2 )


pntA=Point(3, 2)
pntB=Point(7, 8)

print Point.two_point_distance( pntA, pntB )
print pntA.distance_to( pntB )
```